# How I can break my document correctly with DOMPDF?

Tags: html, css, dompdf, html-to-pdf

I want to generate a PDF with DOMPDF through dynamic content. I am creating a table like this:

```
<?php

$language = $this->input->cookie('language');
if (!isset($language))
{
  $language = $core_settings->language;
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
  <meta name="Author" content=""/> 
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="invoice.css" type="text/css" charset="utf-8" />

    <style type="text/css">
      @page {
        margin: 0;
      }
      .pages {
        margin: .5in;
      }
      .other-pages{
        padding:60px;
      }
      .first-page {
        margin: 0in;
        background-color: black;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        position:absolute;
        background-image: url('https://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/example-cover1.jpg'); 
        background-position: bottom center; 
        background-repeat: no-repeat; 
        background-size: 100%;

      }
     .first-page + * {
        page-break-before: always;
      }


    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="pages first-page"></div>
    <div class="other-pages">
        <h2>Title</h2>
        <div class="round"> 
        <table id="table" class="tablesorter" cellspacing="0"> 
            <thead> 
            <tr class="header"> 
              <th width="5%">#</th>
              <th width="95%">Tarea</th>
            </tr> 
            </thead> 
            <tbody> 
            <?php $i = 0; $sum = 0; $row=false; ?>
              <?php foreach ($tasks as $task):?>
                <tr <?php if($row){?>class="even"<?php } ?>>
                  <td><?php echo $i; ?></td>
                  <td><?php echo $task->name; ?><br><?php echo strip_tags($task->description); ?></td>
                </tr> 
              <?php $i++; endforeach;  $row = true; ?>
            </tbody> 
        </table> 
        </div> 
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

When I generate the PDF I have like this:

1. COVER PAGE (without margin)
2. TABLE WITH DYNAMIC CONTENT
3. FULL BLANK PAGE (The problem)
4. TABLE WITH DYNAMIC CONTENT (it's the same table
   always)

How I can fix the blank page?

NOTE: The content of my table depends of the content, so the height depends of the content, I cannot supose X fields and break page.

Answer (score 1):

When dompdf splits content across pages it duplicates the styling on the element. That means the following style is copied to the split element, causing a page break:

```
 .first-page + * {
    page-break-before: always;
  }
```

Since you just want a page break after the first page use the following instead:

```
 .first-page {
    page-break-after: always;
  }
```

---

At least one issue has been logged related to this problem: ["doubling" of page breaks when page-break-before applied to long element](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/issues/854)

Comment: Hi @BrianS thanks for reply me, I try what you said it doesn't work. With your change it appears like this:

BLANK PAGE (full blank page)
COVER PAGE (Background image and in the background of the same image there is a first part of DYNAMIC TABLE PAGE)
DYNAMIC TABLE PAGE

Comment: When I tested with your sample it looked as expected, but I don't have access to invoice.css so there could be some additional styling affecting the layout. You might need to adjust the height of `.first-page`. dompdf doesn't always handle an element with 100% page height quite how you would expect.

Comment: Hi again BrianS, I try as you said (without invoice.css) and doesn't work, in fact what I need is just to put a background imagen in the first page with margin 0, and then I want to print a big dynamic table with margin, but thanks for you help =)

Comment: Using the suggested edit the PDF [renders as expected for me in dompdf v0.6.1](http://eclecticgeek.com/dompdf/debug.php?identifier=bab9206b7d81171bd00a6103e8db8d98). It might help to see the actual HTML produced by your script.